# Git, how to tell what changed when merging a file 'deleted by us'

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

1. I delete a file in a feature branch because I have refactored its code elsewhere.
2. Develop branch has altered the code in this file to fix a bug.
3. I merge develop branch into my feature branch to keep it up to date while I continue work on the feature.

I get a 'Deleted by us' conflict for the file in question.

How do I get a diff of the changes made to the file on the develop branch so I can re-implement those changes into the refactored code on my feature branch?

Comment: Can't you just view the diff in the merge conflict mode?

Comment: That just diff's the deleted (ours) empty file vs the existing (theirs) altered file.
What I want is to be able to see the changes that were made in theirs which caused the conflict.

Comment: Do you know the commit at which you created your feature branch? Compare that commit to the develop branch `git diff sha...develop`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to look in index slot #1, and compare it to what's in index slot #3, for the path:

```
git diff :1:path :3:path
```

You can also *extract* the various index-slot versions, using `git checkout-index`, and then inspect them with ordinary file manipulation rather than just with Git tools.  The `git mergetool` program does the latter, so if you use `git mergetool` you'll have both versions of the file.  (I never use `git mergetool` myself.)

#### What does all this mean?

Any merge, by definition, has three inputs.  The three inputs are *commits*,<sup>1</sup> which contain snapshots of files, so usually the three inputs result in three versions of each file.  Those three file versions wind up these numbered slots in the index: that is, for some file `path/to/file.ext` that is being merged, there is a `:1:path/to/file.ext`, a `:2:path/to/file.ext`, and a `:3:path/to/file.ext`.  (When—as in this case—one of the branches *deletes* a file one of these three entries is nonexistent.)

Let's list the index slots in backwards order, because the last one is the key here:

- **Slot 3 (Theirs)** holds *their* file, at the tip of the `develop` branch: you ran `git merge develop`.  Remember, each commit is a full and complete snapshot of all files.  It's not a set of *changes*, it's just a snapshot.  Yet somehow, Git knows that they *changed* some particular file.  Changed, with respect to *what?*
- **Slot 2 (Ours)** holds the file from your own current commit (also known as `HEAD`).  In this case, some file in `HEAD` has been deleted.  But: how does Git know you *deleted* the file?  Deleted, with respect to *what?*
- **Slot 1 (Base)** holds the file from the *merge base*.  That's the *what* in both of these.

The merge base is the (single / best) common commit from which your divergent branch-tips started.  Git compares this commit—the commit as a whole, really—to each of the two branch-tip commits (as a whole), in order to match up files.<sup>2</sup>  Then, having matched up all the files in the three commits, Git will start the whole "put some files into special slots" process.

That is, if we draw the commit graph when you start your `git merge`, it looks something like this—though the exact details will vary, and usually the graph is a lot harder to scan to find `B` and `R` (`HEAD` or commit `L` is usually very easy to find):

```
          o--...--L   <-- our-branch (HEAD)
         /
...--A--B
         \
          o--...--R   <-- develop
```

Commits `A` and `B` (and everything earlier than A too) are on *both* branches, and are therefore shared, but `B` is the *best* one, because it's the *last* shared one.

In order to do the merge, Git has compared `B` vs `L` to see what *we* changed, and `B` vs `R` to see what *they* changed.  Files that no one changed are the same in all three commits, so Git uses any version of such files.  For files that only *they* changed, Git takes their version of that file, from commit `R`.  For files that only *we* changed, Git takes our version of that file, from commit `L`.

For files that we *both* changed, in some way—including "delete the file entirely"–Git has to work harder.  Now it becomes important to understand that the index—the thing from which Git makes *new* commits—has an expanded role during merging.

Normally, the index has just one slot for each file.  This slot is numbered, but it's the number-zero slot so you generally don't do anything special to refer to it: you just tell Git to `git add somefile` to copy the file *`somefile`* from the work-tree into the index, making it ready to commit.

For the merge case, though, where both we and they did something to a file, Git needs *three*—well, *up to* three—copies of each file.  So for this particular case, Git puts the *merge base* version of the file from commit `B` into index slot #1.  Git moves our version of the file (from commit `L` and already in index slot #0) into index slot #2, and puts the other version of the file from commit `R` into index slot #3.

For a removed file (this particular case) Git leaves slot #2 or #3 empty, depending on who removed the file.  For an add/add conflict—where the file doesn't exist in `B` but does exist in both `L` and `R`—Git leaves slot #1 empty.  (There's no such thing as a delete/delete conflict: if we both deleted the file, Git just deletes the file and moves on.  But there are some rename cases, which are trickier.)

When the merge stops with a merge conflict, these index slots remain populated with the three, or in this case two, versions of the file.  You can therefore inspect the index, look at higher-stage (nonzero) slots, and know which files have conflicts.  The various Git tools, including `git status` and `git diff`, do this.

When you've fixed the conflicts—by whatever means—you must then tell Git to clear out the higher-stage slots and put a good copy of the file into index slot #0.  The easiest way to do this is to `git add` the correct version of the file.  (If there is no correct version—if it should be gone—you can `git rm` the file, removing it from all index slots and the work-tree.  In general, if it's not in the work-tree, `git add` also removes it from the index, though I'm in the habit of `git rm`-ing conflicted files that should just go away, so I have not tested whether `git add` is consistent about removing the higher-stage entries here.  If it's not in the work-tree, `git rm` removes it from the index, complains about it not being in the work-tree, and then all is good.)

---

<sup>1</sup>It is possible, in sneaky special cases, to merge files that have not yet been committed.  This occurs with `git checkout -m` or `git stash apply`, for instance.  In this case, Git normally just moves items from slot 0 to slot 2 as needed ... and changes that are in the work-tree, but were never committed, *can* be mangled and/or lost by tools that expect slot #2 to be a safe copy of what was in the work-tree!  (This is one reason I dislike `git stash`.)  But running `git merge` doesn't invoke this weird path, and in fact it complains and aborts if your repository is not in a nice ready-to-start-a-merge state.

<sup>2</sup>This is where rename detection comes in.  If you've renamed some file in your commit, what *was* `:1:path/to/file.ext` might now be `:2:path/different/file.ext` or `:2:path/to/different.ext`.  Those were detected as the same file, even though it now has two different names.  There's a minor flaw here, because the slots aren't linked together for the full duration of the merge.  If the merge stops with a conflict, it's hard to recover the fact that `2:path/to/different.ext` goes with `:1:path/to/file.ext`, for instance.  Git *prints* the information, so it might still be in a window you can see on your laptop or whatever, but it's not recorded elsewhere.

---

#### Footnote: more-tangled graphs

Here's an example drawing of a branch with some repeated merges:

```
...--A--B--C--D--G--H--K   <-- branch1
         \     \     \
          E-----F--I--J--L   <-- branch2
```

Here, `F` and `J` are both merge commits, with two parents: the two parents of `F` are `E` and `D`, and the two parents of `J` are `I` and `H`.  If you run `git checkout branch2; git merge branch1` you'll be attempting to make a new merge commit `M` whose first parent is `L` and second is `K`.  The merge base here is commit `H` because starting at `K` and working backwards, we get to `H`, while starting at `L` and working backwards, we get to `J` and then—simultaneously, as it were—to both `I` and `H`, and as we already got to `H` along the top, that's the merge base.

Note that merge base computation is symmetric.  If we `git checkout branch1 && git merge branch2`, Git still picks `H` as the merge base.  If the merge base isn't obvious, though, you can run:

```
git merge-base --all branch1 branch2
```

which will produce all the candidates for "best merge base".

Ideally, there is just one.  However, a history that looks like this:

```
...--o--o---A--...   <-- branch1
         \ /
          X
         / \
...--o--o---B--...   <-- branch2
```

where both `A` and `B` are merge commits that are "equally close" to both branch tips, has *two* merge bases.  This arises by doing a merge from branch1 into branch2 and immediately also doing a merge, with `git merge --no-ff`, from branch2 into branch1, sometimes called a criss-cross merge.

In this ambiguous merge base case, there's no single best candidate.  Since merges are normally symmetric anyway, the *contents* of commits `A` and `B` here might well be the same.  In that case, it would not matter which of `A` and `B` Git were to choose.  But if the contents differ, it does matter, and this is where Git's *recursive merge* comes in.  When there are multiple merge bases, Git will first, as an inner merge, merge the two merge bases (using *their* best common ancestor, whatever that is) and make a new commit from the result.  Git will use that new commit's contents as the merge base for the outer merge.

The `-s resolve` merge strategy (not the default) picks one of the two, `A` or `B`, at apparent-random (really, just whatever's more convenient in the algorithm).  If `A` and `B` have the same content, this works fine; if not, the inner merge from the recursive "merge A and B first" *may* produce a better result. It produces something of a mess if the recursive merge has conflicts.  (It's generally wise to avoid criss-cross merges.)

Comment: Excellent answer. If the two branches have already been merged one or more times since the branch was originally created is the 'best' commit now the last commit in the previous merge? Or does it still start from 'B' (as per your example)?.

Comment: Because a merge commit records *both* branch tips (as its two parents), the shared commit is now the tip of the other branch—commit `R` in the graph above. That's true as long as you do a real merge, but not for `git merge --squash`, nor for anything else that makes an ordinary commit after invoking the merge machinery (`git cherry-pick` and `git revert` for instance just make ordinary commits).

Comment: Months later and I come back to this answer again and again. Such an excellent answer deserves more up-votes.